# How to create a rails form with checkboxes which uses GET?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, forms, checkbox, get

The intended URL is

```
"versions/compare/id1/id2"
```

Obviously, this doesn't work, but shows the intention

```
<%= form_tag("/versions/compare/", :method => "get") do %>
  <% versions.each do |v| %>
    <% v.id == @version.id ? current_class = " current" : "" %>
    <li class="version-list <%= current_class %>">
       <%= check_box_tag(:compare_version, v.id) %>
       <%= link_to v.user.name, version_path(v) %>, 
    </li>
  <% end  %>
  <%= submit_tag("Compare") %>
<% end #form tag
 %>
```

The code above produces http://localhost:3000/versions/compare/?utf8=%E2%9C%93&compare_version=13&compare_version=12&commit=Compare

Is there a way to modify the form (+ JS?) so that it gets the desired URL?

```
"versions/compare/id1/id2"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to understand how form_tag work, it can not change the url after rendering the document.

If you want to change the url, use jquery to change it.

Or, just submit the form into some other url like

```
<%= form_tag("/comparing_version")
```

and then, in the controller, after processing everything, you redirect user to

"versions/compare/id1/id2"

Comment: Wouldn't that be possible with JavaScript, though? I could add an additional non-rest action to the controller for the purpose of rewriting the URL, but was hoping this could be done in the client.

Comment: Yes, of course I can be done with javascript/jquery. You need to create a handle for the submit event of the form, then change the action url of the form before it is submitted to server

Comment: After some experimentation, I went with submitting the form to a new action in the controller. My Ruby is better than my JS. Thanks for the suggestions!